# How to skip all tests if beforeAll failed? Using Jasmine and Protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I need to skip all `it()` if `beforeAll()` failed, but all solutions that I found don't work - `beforeAll(`) throw an error but all of `it()` still executes and gets marked as `'failed'`

I've tried:`stopSpecOnExpectationFailure: true,` and Jasmine `pending()` option but those still do not work.

Answer (score 2):

Does this solution fits your needs?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-fail-fast

or

https://github.com/pmowrer/jasmine-fail-fast

I know that suggest npm-packages is not a real 'answer' but I've been seeing this type of questions every couple of months and it usually ends up with using some ready and working solution (like above)

**Update:** I will appreciate if you will come up with your own solution and share it

**Update 2:** Also I will share one wacky way you can do it.

You will need Protractor 6 (because it uses latest jasmine version)

Let's say you tests are depending on the presences of some element.
You can do this in your `beforeAll` :

```
let elementIsPresent = await myElement.isDisplayed()
```

```
it('should test if element is present', function() {
   if(elementIsPresent) {
      // do your thing
   } else {
    pending('skipping test')
  }
});
```

You need to be aware of a couple of thing:

- Protractor below version 6 will mark this test as 'failed' (instead skipping)
- I can not use arrow functions in your `it` blocks

Comment: I've tried `protractor-fail-fast` but in the case when `beforeAll` fails - the first `it` in the file still marked as **failed**, and the rest are marked as **skipped**

Comment: @d_kas it's hard to say why it's acting like that without seeing the whole code. Also please check update 2

Comment: @ Yuriy Gerasimovich, well, I didn't know about the version and use protractor 5. Thanks for the information, I will update the version and check how it works

Comment: @d_kas I not recommend to use this approach. Just an example in case fail-fast will not do the trick...

Comment: unfortunately if `beforeAll` fails the `protractor-fail-fast` still marks as **fail** first `it()` and marks as **skipped** the other `it() 's`. So I use `pending()`, this is not exactly what I was looking for, but it works fine